# Ant + Keeping a control value

Tags: java, file, ant, controls

I need to keep a control value (possibly inside a file), in order to decide whether to execute a task or not.

I'm coming from here: [Ant: How can I subtract two properties (containing timestamps)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239236/ant-how-can-i-subtract-two-properties-containing-timestamps)

What I want to do, is to check if the control value is equal to a period (mmYY). If it is equal, nothing will be done, but if they are not, the control value should be updated.

For example:

```
<task dosomethingifcontrolvaluediffers>
control value is 0000
(calculated) property is: 0110
Then, control value should now be 0110.

</task>
```

I was thinking of keeping the value in a separate file, and if rewriting is neccessary, then truncate the file and updating, but

1) Cant find a way to do this

2) Dont know how.

3) scripting ? Would be my favorite choice, but dont know howto in js.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be done outside of Ant.  Write a script in whatever language you know (bash, Python, JavaScript, etc.) that does the calculation, does the check, and calls Ant using that value as a parameter if needed.

Ant's not intended to be a scripting language.  People get into trouble when they try to make it so.

Comment: Sh*t. I was hoping the "ant is no scripting language" wouldnt come up.

The thing is that ant is the only "scripting" possibility I have in this project.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  You can't use a batch or command file on Windows, or a cshell in *nix?  You always have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but, you may be able to do this:

use the condition task like so

```
<condition property="exectask">
   <equals arg1="${prop1}" arg2="${prop2}" trim="true"/>
</condition>
```

And then call a target based on the property value

```
<target name="dosomethingifcontrolvaluediffers" unless="${exectask}">
</target>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I see what you mean, but heres the thing. prop1 can be calculated, but my question is "how do i get prop2". Plus, how can I update it inside the target.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it :S Maybe prop2 is the control value?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by duffymo, Ant is not a scripting language.
Though you can use a scripting language like javascript inside of Ant, see the [`scriptdef` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html) for details.
You can define your own tasks like this:

```
<scriptdef name="nameOfTheTask" language="javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        (your script goes here)
    ]]>
</scriptdef>
```

You can use the new task like this:

```
<nameOfTheTask/>
```

You also mentioned that you like to store a value in a file. This can be done with the [`echo` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html):

```
<echo file="yourFile">aProperty=${aProperty}{line.separator}</echo>
```

This writes the value to the file *yourFile*. The output is for example:

```
aProperty=some value
```

You can read the value again in a script with the [`loadproperties` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html):

```
<loadproperties srcFile="yourFile" />
```